# Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.Update-migration

Tags: c#, migration

```
public class CommentedList
{
    [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FavoriteListId")]
    public int FavoriteListId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public virtual FavoriteList FavoriteList { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

This is my commented list model when I update database this error appears and I cant fix it.

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_CommentedList_User_UserId' on
> table 'CommentedList' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
> Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
> FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: What does "can't fix it" mean?  Can you follow the advice in the error message?

Comment: This is the error message and ı cant find solution